# Monitoring Multiple Directories For Adding / Removing Files in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to monitor cross-platform if some files are created/removed from certain directories.

I've tried to use fs.watch:

```
let dirs = ['/tmp', '/home/user', './some-dir']

dirs.forEach(function(dir) {
   fs.watch(dir, (evt, filename) => {
      if (filename && evt === "rename") {
        console.log(evt, dir, filename)
      }
   })
})
```

Above code will keep returning latest directory in the array. In the same time, the file was added/removed from the random directory. The behavior of returning latest directory name in forEach cycle is logical. So the question is how can I get correct directory name?

There are some nice third-party modules around such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar But it has lots of dependencies, so I'm trying to keep up with native Node solution for now.

Comment: Would inotify (https://github.com/c4milo/node-inotify) work? It's just a wrapper for a system level utility (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Comment: node-inotify - monitoring file system events in Gnu/Linux // Looks cool, but is it for Linux only? I'm searching for solution working smoothly cross-platform

Comment: Good point...looks like node-watch (https://github.com/yuanchuan/node-watch) might be better for you. It wraps fs.watch, has a small dependency footprint and can watch multiple files/directories `watch(['file1', 'file2'], console.log);`

Comment: Node-watch looks promising. The author positioning it as enhancements for fs.watch (with 0 dependencies) which is cool. Will give it a try. Also, I'm curious is it fancy enough to handle multi-firing events which are annoying drawback of fs.watch

Answer (score 1):

There is a package [Chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) for the NodeJS, which is actually a business standard. Chokidar is a cross-platform solution that works well not only under Linux.